# Glassfish allow only GET and POST methods

Tags: java, methods, glassfish

After deploying the ear i needed to hide the methods of our application in glassfish 4.1.1 so in web.xml i added the following :

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>https</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                         <http-method>GET</http-method>
                         <http-method>POST</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

So when i check with curl :

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS --insecure https://address
```

I get the following :

```
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done does not disable the methods not listed (e.g. PUT, DELETE), but rather forces authentication should these methods be used.  If you don't want to support a particular HTTP method, you can build a webapp which simply has no support for that particular method.

For example, if your deployed application exposed a certain REST endpoint to GET and POST, but not PUT, then most likely if someone tried to access it with PUT they would already be getting some kind of method not supported error.  You could also take it a step further, and actually define that endpoint for PUT, but then throw an exception, return a custom error message, etc.

Read [here](https://coderanch.com/mobile/t/642152/disable-HTTP-methods-glassfish) for more information.

Comment: @Time Biegeleisen, Thanks for the reply, so now i dont have any other solutions except the build of a webapp ?

Comment: @BOUKANDOURAMhamed What I am saying is that if you want certain methods (e.g. PUT) to be blocked in your deployed application, then handle it in the application layer.